# How to get recent folders via microsoft graph REST API

Tags: onedrive, microsoft-graph-api

I want to fetch my recent folders via the Microsoft Graph REST API.
This API contains the following:

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/recent

According to the [references](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/drive_recent) the result should look like this:

```js
{
  "value": [
    {
      "id": "1312abc!1231",
      "remoteItem":
      {
        "id": "1991210caf!192",
        "name": "March Proposal.docx",
        "file": { },
        "size": 19121,
        "parentReference": {
          "driveId": "1991210caf",
          "id": "1991210caf!104"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "1312def!9943",
      "name": "Vacation.jpg",
      "file": { },
      "size": 37810,
      "parentReference": {
        "driveId": "1312def",
        "id": "1312def!123"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

If the results was like this I could get the parent folder by using the driveId and id of the parentReference but in my results I only get the driveId. This causes the need to do one extra call to graph to fetch the folder.

This means I need 3 calls to the graph API to fetch a recent folder.

My question is if there is a way to also fetch the id or the parentReference so I only need two calls or if there even is an easier way for fetching recent folders?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Sadly the answer is no. 'Recents' feature is pretty bare. They could extend it and provide more flexibility. 
If this is critical for you, you can always create a request at:
https://officespdev.uservoice.com/